# Scaffolding in pylons

Tags: python, pylons

Is there anything similar to rails' scaffolding for pylons? I've been poking around google, but only found this thing called dbsprockets, which is fine, although probably way too much for my needs. What I really need is a basic CRUD that is based on the SQLAlchemy model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is super old, but hell: http://code.google.com/p/formalchemy/

Gives you basic crud out of the box, customizable to do even relatively complex things easily, and gives you a drop-in Pylons admin app too (written and customizable with the same api, no magic).

Comment: <del>[Is the project dead?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/formalchemy/60_hhkIJt14)</del>http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/scaffolding.html

Answer (score 5):

I hear you, I've followed the Pylons mailing list for a while looking for something similar. There have been some attempts in the past (see [AdminPylon](http://adminpylon.devjavu.com/) and [Restin](http://code.google.com/p/restin/)) but none have really kept up with SQLAlchemy's rapidly developing orm api.

Since DBSprockets is likely to be incorporated into TurboGears it will likely be maintained. I'd bite the bullet and go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating an old question. DBSprockets has been replaced by [sprox](http://sprox.org/) which learns a lot of lessons from it and is pretty cool.

It isn't quite the throwaway 'scaffolding' that Rails provides, it is more like an agile form generation tool that is highly extensible.